# Unable to use forEach in Flutter Dart for array with just Strings

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I'm trying to fill an array with the info of another array that is obtained from an API call.

I'm using the for each function of the Array with the data but I'm getting this error:

***E/flutter (21633): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'***

I understand it is because I'm using the **imdbID** as the index and that is a String however in my response from the API all the items on the Array come as String.

Example:

```
{
    "Title": "The Avengers",
    "Year": "2012",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "04 May 2012",
    "Runtime": "143 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
    "Director": "Joss Whedon",
    "Writer": "Joss Whedon (screenplay), Zak Penn (story), Joss Whedon (story)",
    "Actors": "Robert Downey Jr., Chris Evans, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Hemsworth",
    "Plot": "Earth's mightiest heroes must come together and learn to fight as a team if they are going to stop the mischievous Loki and his alien army from enslaving humanity.",
    "Language": "English, Russian, Hindi",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 38 wins & 79 nominations.",
    "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Ratings": [
        {
            "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
            "Value": "8.0/10"
        },
        {
            "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
            "Value": "91%"
        },
        {
            "Source": "Metacritic",
            "Value": "69/100"
        }
    ],
    "Metascore": "69",
    "imdbRating": "8.0",
    "imdbVotes": "1,263,208",
    "imdbID": "tt0848228",
    "Type": "movie",
    "DVD": "N/A",
    "BoxOffice": "$623,357,910",
    "Production": "Marvel Studios",
    "Website": "N/A",
    "Response": "True"
}
```

Here is my Current code for my call:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetPeliculas(title, tipo) async {
    var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[my API key]&t=$title';

    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if(extractedData == null){
        return;
      }
      final List<Pelicula> loadedPeliculas = [];
      extractedData.forEach((imdbID, data) {
        loadedPeliculas.add(Pelicula(
          imdbID: imdbID,
          imdbRating: data['imdbRating'],
          metaScore: data['Metascore'],
          plot: data['Plot'],
          poster: data['Poster'],
          title: data['Title'],
          type: data['Type'],
          year: data['Year'],
        ));
      });     
      _items = loadedPeliculas.reversed.toList();
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
```

So is there a way to fill the *loadedPeliculas* Array with the information from the API call, or move in the Response Array when there is no INT value for it?

Kind Regards.

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you are trying to do. That error is typical when you are trying to index a list using a string, but it's not clear why you are using a list at all when the data coming in is a map. As it stands, using `forEach` on that map will loop you through each key-value pair in that map, but trying to treat each value in that pair as a map in its own right is just asking for trouble. Either you didn't post the actual data you are getting from the API or you really need to clarify what it is you are trying to do and how.

Comment: Im trying to move each item that I get on the response to be pushed to loadedPeliculas, the problem is that the response doesn’t bring any int value as a unique value

Comment: Why do you need an int value? What's wrong with just using `imdbID`?

Comment: ImdbID is a String and using forEach doesnt work with a string value for a Key, as to why am I doing this it is the only method I learned to fill the array I ultimately return, if you have any other way please let me know

Comment: `forEach` works just fine with a string for a key, since that's what maps are. I think you need to take a look at the error message and the _exact line of code that is throwing it_, then see if you can figure out what is really going on.

Comment: Sure will and send the info back thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any specific reason for casting your response to `Map<String, dynamic>`. A `List` should work just fine.

This should work as well:

```
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as List;
      if(extractedData == null){
        return;
      }
      final List<Pelicula> loadedPeliculas = [];
      extractedData.forEach((data) {
        loadedPeliculas.add(Pelicula(
          imdbID: data['imdbID'],
          imdbRating: data['imdbRating'],
          metaScore: data['Metascore'],
          plot: data['Plot'],
          poster: data['Poster'],
          title: data['Title'],
          type: data['Type'],
          year: data['Year'],
        ));
      });
```

Edit: You might not even have to add `as List`

Comment: Thank you for that, I tried but it is giving me a new error:

E/flutter (22096): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'

Comment: You cannot interchange `as List` and `as Map`. The response is either one or the other - it cannot be both.

Comment: @Abion47 I'm not interchanging anything, `json.decode` is `dynamic` and should be typecasted for clarity. Poster was already using `List` so he might as well change the response to `List`.

Comment: The returned value from `json.decode` has a type of `dynamic`, but that doesn't mean you can treat that value as whatever type you want. `dynamic` is just hand-wavey jargon for "ignore static type checking on this variable", but runtime type errors can and will happen if you abuse it. If the stringified JSON it parses represents a map (i.e. `'{"a": 1}'`, casting the return value to a list will result in a type cast error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rey,

Your Answer got me to the final Answer the Problem as you Abion47 mentioned was that I was mapping the response.

Although it gave me the error on my previous Comment I was now able to move inside the JSON array using this code:

```
try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      }
      final List<Pelicula> loadedPeliculas = [];
      final size = extractedData.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        loadedPeliculas.add(Pelicula(
          imdbID: extractedData['Search'][i]['imdbID'],
          poster: extractedData['Search'][i]['Poster'],
          title: extractedData['Search'][i]['Title'],
          type: extractedData['Search'][i]['Type'],
          year: extractedData['Search'][i]['Year'],
        ));
      }
```

Thanks to the Both of you I got it working.

Thank you so much

Comment: Judging from the way you are indexing data out of `extractedData`, it seems that the example JSON data you posted in your question body is not the data you were actually receiving and trying to manipulate. In the future, posting _that_ data will get you much more accurate answers and less of people trying to probe you for what the _real_ problem is (as opposed to what you say it is).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will do so from now on.